# Inherit TransientModel and have two views ( website.config.settings )

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9, odoo-view

I am trying to inherit the Website settings menu and have two views. website.config.settings is a models.TransientModel

When I am inheriting that and viewing with a new menuitem it overwrites the previous view. Like - There are two views now, the new record I defined named Website Event Settings . When I click on that it loads the new modified view but when I click on existing Settings menu, it shows nothing.

In summary, the existing website settings menu not working and new menu does. I need both of them.

The py code and record view I used are following -

```
class cofair_website_design_config(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'website.config.settings'
    _inherit = 'website.config.settings'

    event_title = fields.Char(related='website_id.event_title', string='Event Title')
```

XML:

```
<record id="view_website_event_config_settings" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Website Event Settings</field>
        <field name="model">website.config.settings</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form class="oe_form_configuration">
                <header>
                    <button string="Apply" type="object" name="execute" class="oe_highlight"/>
                    <button string="Cancel" type="object" name="cancel" class="oe_link"/>
                </header>
                <div>
                    <group string="Event Page Section">
                        <group>
                            <field name="event_title_color"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </div>
            </form>
        </field>
</record>

<record id="action_website_event_configuration" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Website Event Settings</field>
    <field name="res_model">website.config.settings</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="target">inline</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="view_website_event_config_settings"/>
</record>

<menuitem id="menu_website_event_settings" parent="website.menu_website_configuration" name="Website Event Settings" action="action_website_event_configuration"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of renaming the modules (which causes relational error), I found a workaround. I have inherited the main settings and put a view id there and called it with menuitem -

```
<!-- Bring settings menu out -->
<record id="website.action_website_configuration" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Website Settings</field>
    <field name="res_model">website.config.settings</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="target">inline</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="website.view_website_config_settings"/>
</record>

<menuitem id="website.menu_website_website_settings" parent="website.menu_website_configuration" name="Website Admin" action="website.action_website_configuration"/>
```

Then I called my record action and it loaded the view and action. Another catch point is I had to show website_id to show the values of specific websites or the transient model will always be empty.

Comment: Okay, great...you should mark your answer as accepted since you figured it out and it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

Change the `_name` attribute in your model definition to something else and also modify the xml appropraitely.

```
class cofair_website_design_config(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'something.else'
    _inherit = 'website.config.settings'

    event_title = fields.Char(related='website_id.event_title', string='Event Title')
```

`ir.ui.view`

```
<field name="model">something.else</field>
```

and `ir.actions.act_window`

```
<field name="res_model">something.else</field>
```

That should copy all the fields and methods from `website.config.settings` to the new model `something.else` and keep it separate from `website.config.settings`

Comment: I tried that but website.config.settings have reference to other model and it won't let new view to save. I found a workaround, by inheriting the website record action and menutime, I put a view Id in the record and overwritten main menu item. By that I didn't had to change the model name.